# Kafka connector to poll 3rd party REST API?

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am new to Kafka and I am having some issues understanding whether I should write a producer client or a connector. Basically, let's say I have a 3rd party RESTful API that I need to poll regularly, put the data in Kafka and then use a Kafka sink connector to put it in my DB after some transformations.

Now, my main question is: to get the data from the 3rd party RESTful API: does it make sense to write a custom Kafka source connector? Or should I just write a Kafka producer client that polls the API regularly and then sends the data to Kafka? I am planning to use kafka-python for the potential producer client (and python code in general).

Also: Kafka connect is just a Java framework, so I can only write a custom connector in Java?

Thanks!

So far I haven't tried anything as I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

> Kafka connect is just a Java framework, so I can only write a custom connector in Java?

Yes (well, JVM framework, not "Java". I.e. Kotlin, Scala, Clojure, etc will all work).

---

Beyond that, entirely up to you. There already are several projects on Github that have some combination of words `kafka-connnect` + `http` or `rest`...

Or, you can look at other ETL libraries like CamelK, Apache NiFi, TalenD, Streamsets, etc., all of which offer timer-based functions, HTTP clients, and Kafka clients (and database clients).